# mod_rewrite rule to handle base directory but second rule for any sub directories?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to simplify my website structure but it is proving difficult.

1. I need any exact matches of example.com/inventory/ to redirect to example.com/#search/ (I have this working).
2. I need to have any urls that match example.com/inventory/(.*) to load normally and not be redirected to /#search/ (I have this working).
3. I need to have example.com/#search/(.*) redirect to example.com/inventory/$1 except in the following cases:
   -example.com/#search/order-miles/
   -example.com/#search/order-year/
   -example.com/#search/order-price/ example.com/#search/page-(0-9)+/    -example.com/#search/makemodel-(.*)/

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^inventory/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/inventory/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^#search/(.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^#search/(order-miles|order-year|order-price|makemodel)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/inventory/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^inventory$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/#search/ [R,L]
```

It appears this is all working except for the second set of conditions and corresponding rule.

/#search/order-miles/ loads properly (and the other 3 subfolder structures), but the other urls, such as:

https://example.com/#search/nissan-frontier/9017/nissan-frontier/ 
should redirect to 
https://example.com/inventory/nissan-frontier/9017/nissan-frontier/ 
and does not.

Does anyone see a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't use `#` in the URL for the rule. The server isn't even sent the url hash. It has no idea what is a hash or even if one exists on the url. The browser doesn't send that over with the request. They are used by the client side only and typically js will make a separate ajax request with the information passed after the hash. If you look at the developer tools network tab for that request, you would see that the initial page load doesn't even include it.

Comment: You're right. And after removing those 2 conditions it is all working fine. Thank you